Pyspark Encoding
I'm working with the data saved using alteryx workflow to s3 and then we are using pyspark to write that data in redshift
Now problem is
Its encoded using ANSI/OEM Japnese shift-jis as shown below

Now While reading it in pyspark with shift-jis encoding it still failes to parse data properly, below is the example

was parsed to 
while 
Is getting properly parsed 
So My question  is, is ANSI/OEM shift_jis is different than the shift-jis used in pyspark, and f so what can be used to resolve the issue

you can use the encoding='cp932' encoding when reading the file.
The key difference might be that PySpark is using Shift-JIS encoding, but your data seems to be encoded in a Windows-specific variant like cp932 (ANSI/OEM Shift-JIS). try using cp932 as the encoding in PySpark and see if it resolves  the issue.
try this:
df_pd = pd.read_csv('s3://path_to_file.csv', encoding='cp932')

or
df = spark.read.option("bom", True).csv('s3://path_to_file.csv', encoding='cp932', header=True)


It doesn't seem to available on glue spark, getting IllegalArgumentException: cp932

It Look like AWS Glue's PySpark environment does not support the cp932 encoding directly, which might be why you're encountering the IllegalArgumentException. This could be due to limitations in the available encoding support on Glue.
you can try this one using general-purpose encoding like ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1).. lets see if this works.
df = spark.read.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").csv('s3://path_to_file.csv', header=True)

This didn't work at all, thanks for the suggestion though
